# Information Security learning

Tags: cryptography

I'm new in information security. I need some advices about how to start learning about this area. What are the courses I should take? From where can I start? Give me please an outline to pursue to learn about information security.

Comment: Information security is an amazingly broad topic. That's why this website has 27,827 questions about it. Where to start learning depends greatly on your background, the purpose you are learning it for and what focus you want to have. But anyway, such questions are a bad fit for stackexchange, because they are primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What security resources should a white-hat \*developer\* follow these days?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/571/what-security-resources-should-a-white-hat-developer-follow-these-days), and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-learn-penetration-testing-at-home and, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93/professional-certifications-for-it-security , and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/how-to-improve-as-a-security-expert , and many more

Comment: Basically, check the top voted questions in the education tag https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education

Answer (score 1):

The [Defensive Security Podcast](http://www.defensivesecurity.org/) put together an article on that topic - [Entering The Infosec Biz](http://www.defensivesecurity.org/entering-information-security-industry/).

Answer (score 0):

I my self will be taking the OSCP which is now a crest equivalent this is the minimum required to get into the industry out of no where (google OSCP it will be the first result on offensive security). it depends what side of the team you are playing for... as someone else said you could go for the defensive security (booorrinnggg)

Comment: OSCP would be a bad choice to start with . 
I knew ppl with solid Infosec background who failed passing the exam
I would suggest something easier, such as Security + and CEH . 
.

Comment: OSCP or CRT are good for security testers. Less good for secure development people, firewall analysts, etc...

Comment: @Matthew I guess but also disagree! I suppose it depends on your level thus far, personally I think if you want to be able to protect it you need to be able to break it! ;) but I guess that would be a later thing for a developer.

Comment: I don't think they're bad to have, but you can certainly do a lot of useful work in the field without them. I regularly work with specialists who don't have either, but who do a lot of clever things I don't understand, and together we're able to do a lot more than either of us could individually!